# Can you replace events with promises in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, promise

We are using events to manage workflow in our nodejs app. I was wondering, if we can replace events with promises? I perceive events very much ike callbacks where the event name is like function name to be called, hence would switching to promises would be fine? Need experienced peoples opinion on this.

```
add : function(req, res, next){
var workflow = req.app.utility.workflow(req, res);

workflow.on('checkPermissions', function(){
  // If admin is permitted to add Widget template
  var isPermitted = permissions.getPermission(req.user.group, "widget-template", "add");
  console.log("Is permitted to add WidgetTemplate:-", isPermitted);
  if(!isPermitted)
    workflow.emit('exception', 'Not Permitted');
  else
    workflow.emit('validate');
});

workflow.on('validate', function(){
  if(!req.body.wID)
    workflow.outcome.errfor.wID = 'required';

  if(!req.body.wname){
    workflow.outcome.errfor.wname = 'required';
  }

  if(workflow.hasErrors())
    {
      workflow.outcome.errfor.msg = 'Please fill all the fields';
      return workflow.emit('response');
    }
  else
    workflow.emit('add');
});

workflow.on('add', function(){
  var WidgetTemplate = req.app.db.models.WidgetTemplate;

  var fieldsToSet = new WidgetTemplate({
    widgetTempID : req.body.wID,
    name : req.body.wname,
    devType : req.body.devTypes,
    sensors : req.body.sensors,
    properties : req.body.properties? req.body.properties : [],
    multiple_devices : req.body.multiple_devices? req.body.multiple_devices : false,
    added_by : req.user.id
  });
  console.log("FieldsToset", fieldsToSet);
  fieldsToSet.save()
              .then(
                () => {
                  console.log("Widget Template created...");
                  workflow.emit('response');
                }
              )
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Some error occurred", err.code);
                if(err.code == 11000)
                  workflow.emit('exception', 'Duplicate widget template ID');
                else
                  workflow.emit('exception', err);
              });

});

workflow.emit('checkPermissions');
```

}

Comment: If in your app every event can be fired only once then yes, otherwise no, because Promise result can be settle only once.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what "events" you want to replace?  Event emitters and observers are different than the idea of a promise... but sometimes you can take an event-based object and convert it to promises, i.e. readFile can be chunked using events, but can be promisified to read the entire file at once.

Comment: @CodyG. I have edited  the question with code sample. do let me know your views. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main drawback to that is that promises can only resolve once. If your events are of those type, then sure, you can use a promise. But many events want to happen multiple times, and promises are not a good way to represent that.

One alternative would be to use Observables, which have similarities to promises, but can emit an arbitrary number of times. They're powerful and flexible, but they do have a significant learning curve. One popular library for observables is rxjs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Answer (score 2):

Event listener can be replaced with a promise only for events that are supposed to be emitted once, e.g. event emitter `once` method can be promisified. Otherwise multiple promises should be created.

[`p-event`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-event) addresses both cases. It allows to promisify an event that is emitted once:

```
const result = await pEvent(emitter, 'finish');
```

Otherwise, it allows to iterate over promises as long as needed with asynchronous iterators and `for-await-of`:

```
const asyncIterator = pEvent.iterator(emitter, 'data', {
    resolutionEvents: ['finish']
});

for await (const event of asyncIterator) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

As another answer mentions, observables are another pattern that may be useful here. Observables are able to do everything that promises do and more, at the expense of brevity. Since they can emit multiple values, listening for emitted events is a good use case for them.

Answer (score 0):

### Perhaps already answered, but this is how I do it typically:

```
// given you've defined this `Future` fn somewhere:
const Future = fn => {return new Promise((r,t) => fn(r,t))}

// define an eventFn that takes a promise `resolver`
const eventFn = resolve => {
  // do event related closure actions here. When finally done, call `resolve()`
  something.oneventfired = e => {resolve(e)}
}

// invoke eventFn in an `async` workflowFn using `Future`
// to obtain a `promise` wrapper
const workflowFn = async () => {await Future(eventFn)}
```

> Especially for things like `indexedDb` event wrappers to simplify usage.

The above pattern does not require any library or package other than the definition of `Future`. `Future(eventFn)` is a "one-shot" event handler, but it can be utilized to create a repeatable promisified event handler just as one might do with a timer.

I.e., in the `workflowFn` you can just `loop` to re-apply the `await Future(eventFn)` once it completes.

Or you might find this variation of `Future` to be more general purpose

```
class PromiseEx extends Promise {
  resolve(v,...a) {
    this.settled = true; this.settledValue = v;
    return(this.resolve_(v,...a))
  }
  reject(v,...a) {
    this.settled = false; this.settledValue = v;
    return(this.reject_(v,...a))
  }
  static Future(fn,...args) {
    let r,t,ft = new PromiseEx((r_,t_) => {r=r_;t=t_})
    ft.resolve_ = r; ft.reject_ = t; fn(ft,...args);
    return(ft)
  }
}
```